# Hibernate list() throws EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate

We got recently problem in production:

healthcheck involves db query - list() is called on table B simple select, Table A is not related to table B at all. And it is always same A row which is not found, over and over. It seems somewhere is a global state.

we are not using L2 cache.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [**org.xxx.A#bqdsDYEVRRoUjGET**]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1457)
```

Hibernate version:

```
5.2.12.Final
```

Comment: could you please give us the entities and the code with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I am using PlatformTransactionManager to manage transactions. For read operations it was something like

```
try {
  transactionManager.getTransaction();
  readOperations();
  transactionManager.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
  log(e);
}
```

In edge cases if graph of objects is deleted in separate transaction, readOperations() failes with EntityNotFoundException, transaction is never rollbacked or commited. Spring HibernateTransactionManager stores Sessions+Transaction in ThreadLocal, so its never cleaned up, thread continue using same Session object. Next request served by this thread cause Session+Transaction flushing previous unsuccsessful DML and we got repetitive failures.